# jquery if this OR this

Tags: jquery, if-statement

below I have posted a script. It worked fine before I edited line 7. I want to hide a certain div is the width of the screen is a certain size OR the number of list items a certain  has is 1.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $projectWidth = $('.project-images ul').width();
    var $projectLengh = $(".project-images ul li").length();
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > $projectWidth || $projectLengh == 1) {
            $('.controls').hide();
        }
    }
    checkWidth();   
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

This is my HTML & PHP. It's a wordpress project.

```
<div class="project-images-wrapper">
    <div class="project-images">
        <ul class="clearfix">

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_1') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_1'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_2') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_2'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_3') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_3'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_4') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_4'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_5') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_1'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_5') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_2'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_6') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_6'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_7') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_7'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if( get_field('project_image_8') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_8'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_9') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_9'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( get_field('project_image_10') ): ?>
        <li><img src="<?php the_field('project_image_10'); ?>" /></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
    <button class="prev"></button>
    <button class="next"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `length` is a property, not a method. I.E. lose the parentheses.

Comment: oGeez: why don't you reply instead of commenting? I added a reference to your comment in my answer

Comment: That just so happened to be an error that I noticed initially. It may or may not be the actual problem and reason for the question, just a contributing factor. Aside from that I'm on mobile and it's easier just to comment... **Revel in the rep!**

Comment: I understand. Jordan, can you give us your html structure in order to check if it is the only pb? The code may be improved...

Comment: OK, so you can use my last edited answer which is cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong usage of length. As said in commentCorrect it by oGeez, you have to use `.length` instead of `.length()`. And your code can also be improved this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Check on document ready
    checkWidth();

    // Check on window resize event
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

// Function to hide if conditions are valid
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() > $('.project-images ul').width() || $(".project-images ul li").length == 1) {
        $('.controls').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code may be improved, but we don't have the OP html nor full js usage also

Comment: Yes, that's probably why oGeez only left a comment instead of going for an answer :)

Comment: You're right ;-) i will comment the question to get more info

Comment: I edited the version to clean a little bit and add comment for understanding, is it better @FrédéricHamidi?